# page refresh before file uploaded on server, alternative to preventDefault function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload file from a form using ajax but I'm facing an issue, when i'm submitting the form the page refreshes so the file is not uploaded completely to the server, here's my code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
     <button id="upload">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

Jquery File:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function(e) {
var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
console.log(form_data);                             
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
    dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
        alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
    }
 });

 });
```

the php file:

```
<?php

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

}

?>
```

I don't want to use the function preventDefault() , do you guys know an alternative to it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please oh PLEASE let us know why you do not want to use the special statement that solves your problem? Alternatively just make the button `type="button"`

Comment: I guess you could also use `<form onsubmit="return false">`. But yeah, why not preventDefault?

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin, so I don't want to prevent the event that goes after form submission of the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you want the form to submit after the file is uploaded? Then add `preventDefault` to your click handler (or use `type="button"`), and add a `$('#myForm').submit()` in the success callback (and of course give the form an ID).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different methods here.

Using `AJAX`, you send information to the server and (normally) wait for a result from the server *without the page refreshing*.

Using `SUBMIT`, you send a request to the server and replace the current page with the result (so any AJAX method will no longer be on the page to receive a result).

On another note, as you mentioned it, what events on your page would occur after submitting the form?.

Comment: The submit event which causes page to refresh.

Comment: That's fine, if you want to perform the ajax method first, and then submit the form, @emilpalsson has your solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot !